# XSLT: outputting element values contingent on values of preceding and following siblings

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I’m working with some XML with a flat structure, in which items are implicitly identified by means of repeated groups of elements, without being properly nested in a single parent element for each item (which is the cause of headaches). I need to transform it, using XSLT, into a version of the same thing, in which certain of these groups are output with different text, depending on the value of one of the elements in the group of sibling elements. So, if the input looks like this:

```
<items>

<item_title>Item 1</item_title>
<text1>Item 1 Text 1</text1>
<text2>Item 1 Text 2</text2>
<text3>Item 1 Text 3</text3>
<text4>Item 1 Text 4</text4>
<text5>Item 1 Text 5</text5>

<item_title>Item 2</item_title>
<text1>Item 2 Text 1</text1>
<flag>Suppress text</flag>
<text4>Item 2 Text 4</text4>
<text5>Item 2 Text 5</text5>

<item_title>Item 3</item_title>
<text1>Item 3 Text 1</text1>
<text3>Item 3 Text 3</text3>
<text4>Item 3 Text 4</text4>

<item_title>Item 4</item_title>
<text1>Item 4 Text 1</text1>
<text4>Item 4 Text 4</text4>
<text5>Item 4 Text 5</text5>

<item_title>Item 5</item_title>
<text2>Item 5 Text 2</text2>
<text3>Item 5 Text 3</text3>
<flag>Suppress text</flag>
<text5>Item 5 Text 5</text5>

</items>
```

I want to output something like this:

```
<items>

<item_title>Item 1</item_title>
<text1>Item 1 Text 1</text1>
<text2>Item 1 Text 2</text2>
<text3>Item 1 Text 3</text3>
<text4>Item 1 Text 4</text4>
<text5>Item 1 Text 5</text5>

<item_title>Item 2</item_title>
<text1>The text of this item has been suppressed.</text1>

<item_title>Item 3</item_title>
<text1>Item 3 Text 1</text1>
<text3>Item 3 Text 3</text3>
<text4>Item 3 Text 4</text4>

<item_title>Item 4</item_title>
<text1>Item 4 Text 1</text1>
<text4>Item 4 Text 4</text4>
<text5>Item 4 Text 5</text5>

<item_title>Item 5</item_title>
<text1>The text of this item has been suppressed.</text1>

</items>
```

I’ve been puzzling over how (and indeed, whether) it might be possible to write an XPath expression that identifies, for each /item_title, whether it has a following-sibling::flag before (in document order) its next following-sibling::item_title, and then for each text element, I could embed this XPath expression in an XPath expression that identifies whether the element’s closest preceding-sibling::item_title meets this criterion (in which case the element would not get output). But I haven’t been able to work out how.

Is this possible through an approach like the one I mention, or through some alternative approach?

This is a problem caused by the fact that I’m dealing with rubbish XML, but that’s what I’ve got.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? -- Note that your output is just as flawed as the input; why don't you take the opportunity to nest it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="title" match="items/*[not(self::item_title)]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::item_title[1])"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="items">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item_title"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="items/item_title[key('title', generate-id())[self::flag[. = 'Suppress text']]]">
  <item title="{.}">
    <item1>The text of this item has been suppressed.</item1>
  </item>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="items/item_title[not(key('title', generate-id())[self::flag[. = 'Suppress text']])]">
  <item title="{.}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('title', generate-id())"/>
  </item>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you get

```
<items>
   <item title="Item 1">
      <text1>Item 1 Text 1</text1>
      <text2>Item 1 Text 2</text2>
      <text3>Item 1 Text 3</text3>
      <text4>Item 1 Text 4</text4>
      <text5>Item 1 Text 5</text5>
   </item>
   <item title="Item 2">
      <item1>The text of this item has been suppressed.</item1>
   </item>
   <item title="Item 3">
      <text1>Item 3 Text 1</text1>
      <text3>Item 3 Text 3</text3>
      <text4>Item 3 Text 4</text4>
   </item>
   <item title="Item 4">
      <text1>Item 4 Text 1</text1>
      <text4>Item 4 Text 4</text4>
      <text5>Item 4 Text 5</text5>
   </item>
   <item title="Item 5">
      <item1>The text of this item has been suppressed.</item1>
   </item>
</items>
```

If you don't want to correct the nesting then use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="title" match="items/*[not(self::item_title)]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::item_title[1])"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="items">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item_title"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="items/item_title[key('title', generate-id())[self::flag[. = 'Suppress text']]]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  <item1>The text of this item has been suppressed.</item1>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="items/item_title[not(key('title', generate-id())[self::flag[. = 'Suppress text']])]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('title', generate-id())"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, Martin. I used a version of your suggested approach using keys (but didn’t need to use generate-id() since, in the full version, /item_title actually has a unique @id attribute which I used instead), and it worked very well. In an ideal world, I would have taken the opportunity to add proper nesting; the trouble is, I’m working with a legacy system and producing output to feed into a platform which has already been built and expects input with the old XML structure, so I used the version that preserves the flat structure.

Answer (score 1):

> I’ve been puzzling over how (and indeed, whether) it might be possible to write an XPath expression that identifies, for each /item_title, whether it has a following-sibling::flag before (in document order) its next following-sibling::item_title

Martin has suggested a better way to approach the problem as a whole using keys, but for reference this specific test can be done by assembling the list of all following sibling `flag` and `item_title` elements in document order and then seeing whether the first out of those is a flag:

```
<xsl:template match="item_title[
   (following-sibling::item_title | following-sibling::flag)[1][self::flag]]">
```

Comment: Thank you, Ian. That’s a neat solution to this specific aspect: I didn’t think of testing position on a union of the two elements as following siblings. As an aside, I imagine this would not work if I was testing on nearest preceding sibling instead of nearest following sibling: whereas preceding-sibling::foo[1] would find the last instance of /foo before the context element, (preceding-sibling::foo | preceding-sibling::faa)[1] would find find the first instance in document order of an element that is a preceding sibling of the context element and is also either a /foo or a /faa, right?

Comment: @MDow correct - when you apply a predicate to a single location _step_ on a reverse axis like `preceding-sibling::` or `ancestor::` then the numbering is reversed - `[1]` is the nearest (last in doc order) and `[last()]` is the furthest (first in doc order).  But when you apply a predicate to a parenthesized expression rather than a single step then the numbering is always in forward order.  So the "reverse" version of this would be `(preceding-sibling::item_title | preceding-sibling::flag)[last()][self::flag]` using `[last()]` instead of `[1]`

Comment: Or alternatively, would `preceding-sibling::*[self::item_title or self::flag][1][self::flag]` work?